# Why can we calculate the Fourier series of $x^2$ in any interval $[-l,+l]$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions, fourier-series

We know that a function must satisfy Dirichlet's Conditions before it can be expanded in Fourier series. And Dirichlet's Conditions **strictly** require *a function to be periodic in the interval in which it is to be expanded*. But $f(x)=x^2$  is not periodic in any real interval $[-l,+l]$.

Then why and how can we calculate the Fourier series of $f(x)=x^2$ in any interval $[-l,+l]$?

Comment: We could just form another function $g$ with period $2l$ such that $g(x)=f(x),\ \forall x\in [-l,l]$, and then find its Fourier series.

Comment: I think it has something to do with periodic extension of f (basically $x^2$ on the interval is repeated for all x outside the interval). I'm not too sure myself though.

Comment: When we say _"let's do a Fourier series of $x^2$"_, we actually mean something very different: _"let's do a Fourier series of a function which coincides with $x^2$ on $[-l,l]$, but then continues periodically in both directions"_.

Comment: that's exactly what @Samrat Mukhopadhyay said earlier. you have to expand $f$ as a periodic function. this trick is mostly used in solving PDE's with Separation of Variables technique when you want to meet a certain boundary condition. also you can expand $f$ to be even or odd or have half wave symmetry.